# getting only the four digits in mysql where condition

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a field name "value" which contains 4 digits, 8 digits and 16 digits. How do I get only the four digits using mysql statement "SELECT" with where condition?

Here are the example.

value

1001
90812323
8928123458341235
0123
4521
84920192
7584

Getting only the "1001,0123,4521 and 7584".

Is this possible?

Comment: If you want the exact numbers, you can use `WHERE column='0123' OR column='1001' OR column='4521' OR column='7584'` you can replace `OR` with `AND` or mix of. If that's what you're looking for. *"Getting only the "1001,0123,4521 and 7584"."* Yet, it's hard to say if those numbers are inside different columns, or all bunched up in the same column. Which is why I didn't put in an actual "answer". Many have been given, yet none have been accepted (so far).

Comment: *"Many have been given"* - And, many have gone. This leaves you with one answer and one comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT value FROM table WHERE LENGTH(value)=4;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM tb WHERE char_length(value) = 4
```

check this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html